# Perl: Setting $day, $month and $year

Tags: perl, date

I've managed to cobble together a script that reads through thousands of log entries and creates a summary of them.  All good so far.  What I also want to be able to do is for it to create a separate summary of the entries from just the last 90 days.

A single entry in the log looks like the following, with newer entries always being added to the bottom of the file :

> Serial No:  10123407
>   Date:       14/08/15
>   Time:       12:58
>   Cycle type: 134 U
>   Hold  time: 0180
>   Cycle No:   1357
>   Dry Time:   00 mins.
>
> Cycle Start
>   12:58.35
>
> Hold Time    0000 Secs
>   Cycle: Failed
>   User_Message 13
>   Ref.to User Manual
>
> Cycle End
>   13:01.32

The code I am using to return the current date and the date 90 days ago is:

```
use POSIX qw(strftime);  
use Time::Local qw(timegm);  
my ($d,$m,$y) = (localtime())[3,4,5];  
print OUT (strftime("%d/%m/%y - ", gmtime(timegm(0,0,0,$d,$m,$y)-90*24*60*60)));  
print OUT (strftime("%d/%m/%y\n", gmtime(timegm(0,0,0,$d,$m,$y))));
```

I'm doing it like this because it's producing my dates in the format I want, the same as in the logs dd/mm/yy and always zero padded.
Using this I get the following output:

> 11/05/15 - 09/08/15

So if I can print it, how can I store the data as the variables: `$day90`, `$month90`, `$year90`, `$day`, `$month` and `$year`.  If I can do that then I think I can do the logical operations necessary to decide if the log entry is within the last 90 days and then create my summary as I want it.

I don't have any preconceived ideas as to how this is done so any and all solutions will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Try [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece).. Se also [Perl - How to get date of Previous wednesday from the given date without using DateTime](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31804463/perl-how-to-get-date-of-previous-wednesday-from-the-given-date-without-using-d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the best ways to compare dates is by converting them to `%Y%m%d` format (or `%Y-%m-%d` if you want something more readable) and then you can compare them as text strings

You can use the core module [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) to do the formatting for you

Here's an example. It defines the input format and the comparison format as `$dmy_format` and `$ymd_format` respectively

The strings for today's date and 90 days earlier are defined and stored as `state` variables the first time `in_range` is called, and so never need to be calculated again. (You will need Perl 5 version 10 or better for the `state` keyword. If that's not available then just use `my` instead and move those definitions *outside* and *immediately before* the subroutine)

The passed parameter is the date in `DD/MM/YY` format. It is parsed and reformatted as `YYYY-MM-DD` and the subroutine returns the result of comparing it with the two boundary dates

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;   # for 'state' variables

use Time::Piece;
use Time::Seconds 'ONE_DAY';


for my $month ( 1 .. 12 ) {
  my $date = sprintf '14/%02d/15', $month;
  printf "date %s is %s\n", $date, in_range($date) ? 'in range' : 'out of range';
}


sub in_range {

    state $ymd_format = '%Y-%m-%d';
    state $dmy_format = '%d/%m/%y';

    state $now = localtime;
    state $today = $now->strftime($ymd_format);
    state $days90 = ($now - 90 * ONE_DAY)->strftime($ymd_format);

    my $date = Time::Piece->strptime(shift, $dmy_format)->strftime($ymd_format);

    $date le $today and $date ge $days90;
}
```

#### output

```
date 14/01/15 is out of range
date 14/02/15 is out of range
date 14/03/15 is out of range
date 14/04/15 is out of range
date 14/05/15 is in range
date 14/06/15 is in range
date 14/07/15 is in range
date 14/08/15 is out of range
date 14/09/15 is out of range
date 14/10/15 is out of range
date 14/11/15 is out of range
date 14/12/15 is out of range
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to get dates into variable i.e split with `/` and store it in variables:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use POSIX qw(strftime);  
use Time::Local qw(timegm);  
my ($d,$m,$y) = (localtime())[3,4,5];  
my ($day90,$month90,$year90) = split(/\//,(strftime("%d/%m/%y", gmtime(timegm(0,0,0,$d,$m,$y)-90*24*60*60))));
my ($day,$month,$year)=split(/\//,(strftime("%d/%m/%y", gmtime(timegm(0,0,0,$d,$m,$y)))));

print "DATE(BEFORE 90 days): $day90 $month90 $year90 \n";
print "DATE(CURRENT): $day $month $year \n";
```

**Output:**

```
DATE(BEFORE 90 days): 11 05 15 
DATE(CURRENT): 09 08 15
```